# OpenCart - remove one category with subcategories from product query

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I've been working to change the query in `getProducts($data = array())` method.

So.. In specific controller I added `exclude_category_id => 65` in `$data` array, which I pass to `getProducts($data)`.

```
$data = array(
    'sort'  => 'p.date_added',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'start' => 0,
    'limit' => $setting['limit'],
    'exclude_category_id' => 65
);
```

In `model/catalog/product.php` in `public function getProducts($data = array())` I added this code:

```
if (!empty($data['filter_category_id'])) {
    if (!empty($data['filter_sub_category'])) {
        $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_path cp LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c ON (cp.category_id = p2c.category_id)";         
    } else {
        $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c";
    }

    if (!empty($data['filter_filter'])) {
        $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_filter pf ON (p2c.product_id = pf.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (pf.product_id = p.product_id)";
    } else {
        $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)";
    }
} else if(!empty($data['exclude_category_id'])){

    // THIS ELSE IF IS ADDED BY ME

    $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c";
    $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)";
}else {
    $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p";
}
```

Deeper in that method I added also:

```
if(!empty($data['exclude_category_id'])){
    $sql .= " AND p2c.category_id != '" . (int)$data['exclude_category_id'] . "'";
}
```

But products from category with `ID = 65` are still visible. Anyone have any idea how to do that?

Comment: This works for main product category, but not if product has subcategory of that main category

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

I added at the beginning of method in `model/catalog/product.php`:

```
public function getProducts($data = array()) {
    $exclude_ids;

    if(!empty($data['exclude_category_id'])){
        $exclude_ids = array($data['exclude_category_id']);

        $this->load->model('catalog/category');

        $results = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($data['exclude_category_id']);

        if($results){
            foreach($results as $result){
                $exclude_ids[] = $result['category_id'];
            }
        }
    }

    if(!empty($exclude_ids)){
        $t = $exclude_ids;
        $exclude_ids = "";

        foreach($t as $id){
            $exclude_ids .= $id.', ';
        }

        $exclude_ids = substr($exclude_ids, 0, -2);
    }
```

and deeper in this function:

```
    if (!empty($data['filter_category_id'])) {
        if (!empty($data['filter_sub_category'])) {
            $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_path cp LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c ON (cp.category_id = p2c.category_id)";         
        } else {
            $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c";
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_filter'])) {
            $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_filter pf ON (p2c.product_id = pf.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (pf.product_id = p.product_id)";
        } else {
            $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)";
        }
    } else if(!empty($data['exclude_category_id'])){ /*********** ADDED ELSE IF *********/
        $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c";
        $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)";
    }else {
        $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p";
    }
```

And little deeper:

```
    if(!empty($data['exclude_category_id'])){
        $sql .= " AND p2c.category_id NOT IN (".$exclude_ids.")";
    }
```

Sorry for chaotic solution, but TIME was the key in this project.